# Joomla jform editor field does not post text when submitted

Tags: forms, post, joomla, editor, field

I'm working on a custom joomla module. It has a form with an "editor" type field. The fields are defined in the related xml file:

```
<form>
    <fields name="main">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            ...
            <field
                name="Message"
                type="editor"
                label="Message"
                filter="safehtml"
                readonly="true"
            />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

When I press the button to submit the form all other form fields are properly submitted, but not the editor field.

I checked that if I change the field type to "textarea", the text gets posted correctly. So it must be something with the editor field type.

What do I  need to do to be able to submit the text entered into the editor field?

Thanks a lot, 
W.

Comment: There is a special separate stackexchange site devoted to joomla [joomla.se]  and I think you'll get an answer there.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the hint!